# What are the differences between Liferay 6.2-ga2 and Liferay 6.2-ga6?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-6.2

I want to migrate from liferay 6.2-GA2 to liferay 6.2-GA6 please kindly let me know what are the steps to be followed and major changes between two versions.

Thank you in advance,
P.V.B.Raju.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the release notes of each release here

https://web.liferay.com/community/releases

Also check the blog for GA6. 
https://web.liferay.com/web/james.falkner/blog/-/blogs/liferay-6-2-ce-ga6-now-available

Starting with GA2 you have to check release notes for each and every release.